# Безопасность авторизации

Tags: php, авторизация, mysql

Занимаюсь на данный момент авторизацией, по средствам PHP + MySQL.
Вот хотел бы попросить, интересные решения безопасности авторизации, может у кого свои интересные решения есть, "поковырять" - кому не жалко, поделитесь. В заранее, благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При авторизации добавляю ключи в сессию:

```
function auth($login, $pass)
{
if((isset($login))&&(isset($pass)))
{
        if(!CheckWord($login))
        return false;
        include("config.php");
        include("sql.php");
        $sql = "SELECT id, Name, access_level FROM ".$config['prefix']."users WHERE login='$login' and pass='".hash_gen($pass)."'";
        $st=false;
        $rs=mysql_query($sql, $conn);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
                $st=true;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['aceess_level'] = $row['aceess_level'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['Name'];
//              $_SESSION['SName'] = $row['SName'];
                $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
                //Генерируем ключи в Сессию!
                $_SESSION['key'] = base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1(utf8_encode($row['id'].$login.$config['key']).$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])));
                $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
                if(HaveNotResume())
                    $_SESSION['resume'] = true;
                else
                $_SESSION['resume'] = false;
                mysql_query("UPDATE ".$config['prefix']."users SET lastaccess=".time()." WHERE id='".$row['id']."'", $conn);
        }
                return $st;
}
}
```

Затем в нужном месте проверяю данные:

```
function FireWall()
{
    include("config.php");
    if($_SESSION['auth'])
    {
        if($_SESSION['key'] == base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1(utf8_encode($_SESSION['id'].$_SESSION['login'].$config['key']).$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Сообщить о попытке взлома т.е добавить ЛОГ в Базу! 
            add_log(5);
            session_destroy();
            return false;

        }
    }
    else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Чего минусуют? Это популярный и надежный способ защиты сессионной куки — поставить на нее подпись. Только надо сказать «подписываю», а не «добавляю ключи». И желательно не одним sha1 обойтись, а использовать HMAC. И желательно объяснить принцип, а не вываливать кучу кривенького кода.

Comment: Мой способ) а дальше по своему вкусу)

Comment: @Ali, если вставка данных от пользователя прямо в sql запрос все еще считается надежным способом, то конечно вопрос `Чего минусуют?` актуален. ;)